# what is the equivent of tab to the left in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a web extensions that lets the user open a tab to the right of the tab the user started in and then preforms some work in that new tab. After the work is done that tab closes. When the work tab closes the user is taken to the next tab to the right of the work tab that just closed. Since the user used the tab to the left of the tab that closes to open it, I think it would be more logical for the user to be returned to the tab they started from.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs

I'm working in Firefox and I see that there are `tabs.goForward()` and `tabs.goBack()` functions, but they are not available in Firefox, only Chrome. Is there a way to get comparable behavior of switch to the tab the left after a tab closes in Firefox?

Comment: Those functions are for history navigation within one tab. What you need is to specify openerTabId to the original tab id when creating the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `openerTabId` for browser.tabs.create will focus the previous tab when you close the newly created tab.

In an asychronous method:

```js
let currentTabs = await browser.tabs.get({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

browser.tabs.create({
  url: "https://example.org",
  openerTabId: currentTabs[0].id
});
```

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create for details.